# How to use instanceof with with a generic function type

Tags: typescript

In the following example, I would like to make sure that the returned type corresponds to the given generic type in a generic function.
Unfortunately when using `result instanceof T`, TypeScript reports the following error: `error TS2693: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`.
Is there a way to check at runtime if the type of an objects corresponds to a generic type?

```
class Foo {
    id: number;
    constructor(id: number) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    name: string;
    constructor(id: number, name: string) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
    }
}

function get<T>(list: Array<Foo>, id: number): T|undefined {
    const result = list.find(e => e.id === id);
    if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
        return undefined;
    }

    if (!(result instanceof T)) { // error TS2693: 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here 
        return undefined;
    }

    return result as unknown as T;
}

const foos = [new Foo(1), new Bar(2, 'bar'), new Foo(3)];

console.log(get<Foo>(foos, 1));
console.log(get<Foo>(foos, 2));
console.log(get<Bar>(foos, 3));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types (and type parameters) are erased during compilation, so you can't say `result instanceof T` because there is not `T` at runtime.

What you can do is pass in the class itself to the function (which is a value and can thus be used at runtime)

```
function get<T>(cls: new (...a: any) => T, list: Array<Foo>, id: number): T|undefined {
    const result = list.find(e => e.id === id);
    if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
        return undefined;
    }

    if (!(result instanceof cls)) {
        return undefined;
    }

    return result as unknown as T;
}

const foos = [new Foo(1), new Bar(2, 'bar'), new Foo(3)];

console.log(get(Foo, foos, 1));
console.log(get(Foo, foos, 2));
console.log(get(Bar, foos, 3));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXoEsAmAXNAHYCuAtgEYCmATgNwbbTDzEQAutpwH8tACnxEyVOgEoUTZtg4ALHBAB0+aAF5ceRpmwBfDPvQZQkGACEwtaNQAeHasTwwESNDqzEw5akU60cxADm2sys7Fw8fILCJBQ0tAA0JF4+0H4BgZJuMtgQpAAOdEJ44iE50PKKSp7e6sneZViGhhgAZqTEvDhs0IHUHAA8ACoAfAKgECLUAO7QAkoLYERgxACekmoj0ENJIIocRACCtLRgqwMuI0kxovHiREMAPh141K0B1HhS7ixsnNC0ah5EAcOp7ThKd6OATUdRbagqL5qZGaUrSLA4VpzDirQrwLGA4Gg5EaADkLzeHzwpKy6JkgI4pFoxGgFKhn0a0BaP0xcwAhAJCaQQbhwitgNR8SwQBBxLSfswGUyWWyqZzuYr+sqAUDhaDIKziABrYjwaYsg1DbTcsL-VqIGAaADaxBmcEQAgAjOIkq7ZhZBAAmJKkyiWGm+t0uAQAZnEAF1tMY-vAQAiQPBAgI+hwBC4kvb4BAkt60ehban05ns-084gCw6koG5doK2mlBmszmBAGG0WknHSkA)